# How to customize a Crystal Reports report in runtime

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I'm working with VS2010 C# and I need to create a report that the user can modify. I've inserted parameter fields and they work fine for text but the problem comes when I add an image to the report. The main idea is that the user can modify the image using a **openFileDialog**. I've inserted an **OLE** object, and loaded a placeholder image. I have a *path* parameter field that I update with the **openFileDialog** and use it as a formula to change the path of the placeholder image.
I'm not sure if this works, because since I've added the image to the report I cannot print it (I'm using the **printToPrinter** method) and it gives me a **ParameterFieldCurrentValueException**.

Upon further research I've found a possible workaround. In this case I would create the **OLE** object and then add it to the report with the following piece of code:

```
private void PictureData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.PictureObject boPictureObject;
        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section boSection;

        rpt.Load("D:\\CPP Net\\RASXIR2Printer\\oleobject.rpt");
        rptClientDoc = rpt.ReportClientDocument;

        String MyfilePath = "C:\\temp\\sample1.jpg";

        //Determine which section to add the picture field to - in this case the report header section
        boSection = rptClientDoc.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.ReportHeaderArea.Sections[0];

        //Add it to the report
        boPictureObject = rptClientDoc.ReportDefController.ReportObjectController.ImportPicture(MyfilePath, boSection, 1, 1);

    }
```

The problem here is that the **ReportClientDocument** class used does not seem to exist in the version I'm working with. Also I have the feeling that even if I manage to make this code work it will still fail to print it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a LOT of research I've found the solution. I'll leave this here in case anyone needs help. All I had to do was add some References. In .NET search for **'CrystalDesicions.RerportAppServer.ClientDoc'** and **'CrystalDesicions.RerportAppServer.Controllers'** and add them.